# What is the output type of Subprocess.communicate?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I was going through official documentation of [Popen.communicate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

```
p = subprocess.Popen('echo hello',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,universal_newlines=True)
r,e = p.communicate()
```

I want to know at which case it will return string output and which case it will return in bytes.(with example would be great)

In the above case `r` type is string.

```
Popen.communicate(input=None, timeout=None)
Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate and set the returncode attribute. The optional input argument should be data to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child. If streams were opened in text mode, input must be a string. Otherwise, it must be bytes.

communicate() returns a tuple (stdout_data, stderr_data). The data will be strings if streams were opened in text mode; otherwise, bytes.
```

Comment: ```text (also known as universal_newlines)``` This is what I am looking for..

Comment: As an aside, you are painstakingly reimplementing `subprocess.run` with fewer features and poorer error handling. Like the documentation tells you, avoid `Popen` when you can, and rely on the documented, debugged higher-level functions available in the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Also, `universal_newlines` was renamed to `text` in Python 3.7. The old alias is a misnomer as well as unwieldy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the text mode used as [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)

> If encoding or errors are specified, or text (also known as universal_newlines) is true, the file objects stdin, stdout and stderr will be opened in text mode using the encoding and errors specified in the call or the defaults for io.TextIOWrapper...
> If text mode is not used, stdin, stdout and stderr will be opened as binary streams. No encoding or line ending conversion is performed.

For future use-cases on well typed libraries, you can use `typing.reveal_type` with static analyzers such as mypy. This makes it quite easy to determine values in your code.

Example, `test.py`

```
from subprocess import Popen
from typing import reveal_type

p1 = Popen("blah", text=False)
reveal_type(p1.communicate())


p2 = Popen("blah", text=True)
reveal_type(p2.communicate())
```

```
> mypy test.py
test.py:5: note: Revealed type is "Tuple[builtins.bytes, builtins.bytes]"
test.py:9: note: Revealed type is "Tuple[builtins.str, builtins.str]"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

You can see here, when `text=False` the values are bytes, when `text=True` the values are strings.

Answer (score 0):

Whether bytes or strings are returned depends on what you pass to the stdout and stderr arguments. These arguments can be either [text streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o), in which case strings are returned, or [binary streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o), in which case bytes are returned.

In your example, you specified `subprocess.PIPE`, which denotes the standard stream (i.e. sys module's [stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) and [stderr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stderr)). In python3, these output strings.